# Java - Comparator to search for substring

Tags: java, search, comparator

I am trying to use binary search to look for a string that contains a substring.

```
ArrayList<String> ch = new ArrayList<String>();
    ch.add("qwerty");
    ch.add("asdfghjkl");
    ch.add("c");
    ch.add("d");
    ch.add("e");
    Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String node1, String node2) {
            if (node1.contains(node2)) {
                return 0;
            }
            return node1.indexOf(node2);
        }
    };


    int pos2 = Collections.binarySearch(ch, "sdf", comparator);
```

Is it possible to use binarysearch instead of using loop. This is giving me an incorrect index.

I am trying to avoid using a string.substring(x,y) where x and y is a fixed value.

Answer (score 2):

[`Collections.binarySearch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method is used to search for an exact match, and not a match based on some substring or some method. Also, for `binarySearch` to work, you should have a sorted array, based on the `Comparator` that you are passing to `binarySearch` method (Although, this doesn't matter here, as it wouldn't work either).

> Is it possible to use binarysearch instead of using loop.

I don't think it is possible to do this without using a loop. If you are really worried about performance, you can write your own binary search implementation, which checks for `contains()` instead of equality.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** You can only do a binary search on sorted collections.
**Solution:** Sort your collection using your `Comparator` before calling `binarySearch()`;

**Problem:** Your comparator must fulfill the interface requirements. For instance, your sorting function must be **transitive**.
**Solution:** The only possible way to achieve that is using a `Comparator` per string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> ch = new ArrayList<String>();
    ch.add("qwerty");
    ch.add("asdfghjkl");
    ch.add("c");
    ch.add("d");
    ch.add("e");
    final String fixedString = "sdf";
    Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String node1, String node2) {
            boolean node1Contains = node1.contains(fixedString);
            boolean node2Contains = node2.contains(fixedString);
            if (node1Contains && !node2Contains) {
                return 1;
            } else if (!node1Contains && node2Contains ) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    };

    Collections.sort(ch, comparator);
    int pos2 = Collections.binarySearch(ch, fixedString, comparator);
    System.out.println("Sorted collection: "+ch);
    System.out.println("Index found: "+pos2);
}
```

Output:

```
Sorted collection: [qwerty, c, d, e, asdfghjkl]
Index found: 4
```

#### The bottom line:

Not taking into account the size of the strings and the cost of calling `contains()` so many times:

- Sorting will take `O(n log(n))` (where `n` is the number of strings) and searching will take `O(log(n))`, thus, overall, `O(n log(n))`.
- Looping will take `O(n)`.

So unless you want to get something like "the string that has the searched string in the least index (closer to its beginning)", you are better off looping through.

Answer (score 0):

The list must be sorted prior to searching for the item as mentioned in the API.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List, T)

Also, the compare function should return -1,0,1 as a response, looks like it is not doing what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Comparators were really meant to compare two objects to determine what their relative ordering should be with respect to one another.  The compare method should return -1 if node1 comes before node2, 1 if it comes after, and zero if they are the same String.

Your compare method returns 0 if one is a substring of the other, and -1 otherwise, so binarySearch will be very confused by this.  Further, binary search assumes the array is sorted, and will only work if you are looking for an exact string in the array, not a string that contains a substring.  You just need to iterate over the array and see if each one contains the substring you are looking for.